# Adding to a database in sqlite through wtforms

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this project that I'm doing and it's an appointment system that I created. The sole purpose is to show how the admin can login to the system and do any type of editing and adding when it comes to those appointments and customers. I have created the database through SQLite. WTForms were used to create different forms to add an , add a customer and to edit both. The problem I am having is that the form works but whenever I add an appointment through the form, it does not add to the SQLite database like it's supposed to.

Here is a picture of the code that has been typed:

```
command = """ SELECT MAX (id) 
    FROM {a}

          """.format(a='Customer')
cursor.execute(command) 
AddedCustomer_data = cursor.fetchone()  
AddedCustomer_data = AddedCustomer_data[0]+1 

form = AddCustomer(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)

if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

    Customer = form.Customer.data
    Address = form.Address.data 
    City = form.City.data
    State = form.State.data
    ZipCode = str(form.ZipCode.data)
    EmailAddress = form.EmailAddress.data
    PhoneNumber = str(form.PhoneNumber.data)
    Problem = form.Problem.data

    command = """ INSERT INTO {a}. (Customer, Address, City, State, ZipCode, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, Problem)
    VALUES ('"""+Customer+"""','"""+Address+"""', '"""+City+"""','"""+State+"""','"""+ZipCode+"""','"""+EmailAddress+"""','"""+PhoneNumber+"""',
    '"""+Problem+"""') 


              """.format(a='Customer')
    cursor.execute(command)
    conn.commit()
```

And this is the form: 
class AddCustomer(Form):

```
Customer = TextField(
label = "Customer", validators = [InputRequired()])
Customer_id = IntegerField(
"Customer.id", validators = [InputRequired()])
Address = TextField(
label = "Address", validators = [InputRequired()])
City = TextField(
label = "City", validators = [InputRequired()])
State = TextField(
label = "State", validators = [InputRequired()])
ZipCode = IntegerField(
label = "ZipCode", validators = [InputRequired()])
EmailAddress = TextField(
label = "EmailAddress", validators = [InputRequired()])
PhoneNumber = IntegerField(
label = "PhoneNumber", validators = [InputRequired()])
Problem_id = IntegerField(
label = "Problem.id", validators = [InputRequired()])
Problem = TextField(
label = "Problem", validators = [InputRequired()])
```

Is the anything that I might have typed in wrong or still need to type so that once I add the new customer, its adds to the database in SQLite? I've tried a few different ways and its still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlalchemy` to do this. `WTForms` supports it, too.
It's hard to tell why this is not working without seeing an error trace or actually running the code. Try to print `command` and see if it matches what `sqlite3` expects. You're putting objects like `Customer` and `Address` in a string. Python will use `__str__` of the those objects when it concatenates it with the rest of your sql query.
Another thing you can is to inspect the output of `conn.commit()`. You can just do `print(conn.commit())` and see if anything is actually returned by `sqlite3`.
Or, like I mentioned in the beginning, use an `ORM`. If `sqlalchemy` is too big for your purposes, try other light-weight ORMs like `peewee`.